# Converting decision problems to optimization problems? (evolutionary algorithms)

Tags: optimization, evolutionary-algorithm

Decision problems are not suited for use in evolutionary algorithms since a simple right/wrong fitness measure cannot be optimized/evolved. So, what are some methods/techniques for converting decision problems to optimization problems?

For instance, I'm currently working on a problem where the fitness of an individual depends very heavily on the  output it produces. Depending on the ordering of genes, an individual either produces no output or perfect output - no "in between" (and therefore, no hills to climb). One small change in an individual's gene ordering can have a drastic effect on the fitness of an individual, so using an evolutionary algorithm essentially amounts to a random search.

Some literature references would be nice if you know of any.

Comment: Are all perfect outputs equally perfect? Are all no outputs equally likely to be near to a perfect output?

Comment: For your first question, yes. For your second question, some might be closer to a perfect solution in terms of genetic structure, but from a fitness perspective, since they produce no output they have the same poor fitness as ones that may not be as close.

Comment: You seem to have answered your own question: if there is no hill to climb, any form of hill-climbing optimization just can't get any traction. Other than general hand-waving about incrementalism and partial solutions, it is hard to imagine a general solution is possible.

Comment: A common trick is to introduce stochasticity, either in the genes, or in the "production": then the new fitness becomes the probability of reaching a perfect output, which is now a continuous number. Is that applicable to your problem?

Answer (score 1):

Application to multiple inputs and examination of percentage of correct answers.

True, a right/wrong fitness measure cannot evolve towards more rightness, but an algorithm can nonetheless apply a mutable function to whatever input it takes to produce a decision which will be right or wrong. So, you keep mutating the algorithm, and for each mutated version of the algorithm you apply it to, say, 100 different inputs, and you check how many of them it got right. Then, you select those algorithms that gave more correct answers than others. Who knows, eventually you might see one which gets them all right.

There are no literature references, I just came up with it.

Answer (score 0):

Well i think you must work on your fitness function.
When you say that some Individuals are more close to a perfect solution can you identify this solutions based on their genetic structure?
If you can do that a program could do that too and so you shouldn't rate the individual based on the output but on its structure.